# Jquery wait between user defined functions

Tags: jquery, function, callback, wait

I have two functions, tick and tock. They cause 4 numbers to spin one direction then the other. Each number can ease at a different rate.

I can call both functions but I cannot get the second (tock) to wait until all the numbers have finished moving in the first (tick).

I have looked at other similar questions where a callback is used but I cannot seem to implement this with my example. I either end up with the second function proceeding before the first is finished or as is the case with the code below, only the first function is used.

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var complete = 0;

tick('', function(){tock();});

function tick(a){

    $('#col1 img')
        .delay('1000')
        .animate({bottom:'-=80px'},5000,'easeInOutSine');
        complete++;

    $('#col2 img')
        .delay('1000')
        .animate({bottom:'+=720px'},1000,'easeInOutSine');
        complete++;


    $('#col3 img')
        .delay('1000')
        .animate({bottom:'+=560px'},500,'easeInOutSine');
        complete++;


    $('#col4 img')
        .delay('1000')
        .animate({bottom:'-=240px'},2000,'easeInOutSine');
        complete++;

}

function tock(){
    $('#col1 img')
        .delay('1000')
        .animate({bottom:'+=80px'},2000,'easeInOutSine');

    $('#col2 img')
        .delay('1000')
        .animate({bottom:'-=720px'},2000,'easeInOutSine');

    $('#col3 img')
        .delay('1000')
        .animate({bottom:'-=560px'},2000,'easeInOutSine');

    $('#col4 img')
        .delay('1000')
        .animate({bottom:'+=240px'},2000,'easeInOutSine');
}
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to help but what you're asking is pretty unclear. So tock() runs every four times tick() runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wait until all the animations are done and then call the other function. All jQuery objects implement the [promise interface *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) and they get resolved when any animation finished. Together with [`$.when` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), you can easily achieve what you want:

```
function tick(callback){

    var p1 = $('#col1 img')
        .delay('1000')
        .animate({bottom:'-=80px'},5000,'easeInOutSine')
        .promise();

    var p2 = $('#col2 img')
        .delay('1000')
        .animate({bottom:'+=720px'},1000,'easeInOutSine')
        .promise();


    var p3 = $('#col3 img')
        .delay('1000')
        .animate({bottom:'+=560px'},500,'easeInOutSine')
        .promise();


    var p4 = $('#col4 img')
        .delay('1000')
        .animate({bottom:'-=240px'},2000,'easeInOutSine')
        .promise();

    // $.when returns a new promise which is resolved once each passed promise 
    // is successfully resolved
    $.when(p1, p2, p3, p4).done(callback);
}

function tock(){
    // same as the original code
}

tick(tock);
```

More information about promises / deferreds: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/.

---

Since so much code repetition makes me anxious, here is a refactored version of the `tick` function:

```
function tick(callback) {
    var data = [
        {props: {bottom: '-=80px'}, duration: 5000},
        {props: {bottom: '+=720px'}, duration: 1000},
        {props: {bottom: '+=560px'}, duration: 500},
        {props: {bottom: '-=240px'}, duration: 2000}
    ];
    var promises = [];

    // assuming the elements are in the correct document order
    $('#col1, #col2, #col3, #col4').find('img').each(function(i) {
        var d = data[i];
        promises.push(
            $(this).delay(1000).animate(d.props, d.duration, 'easeInOutSine').promise()
        );
    });

    $.when.apply($, promises).done(callback);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. And thanks very much for tidying up the code. Much appreciated.